# Using Excel VB FtpCommand to list remote directory

Tags: excel, ftp, vba

I need to use FTP Command Function from `wininet.dll` to send some FTP command. It's working when I use `QUIT` command. But when I try to use for example `LS` or `DIR` I get response 0.

```
Private Declare Function FtpCommand Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "FtpCommandA" (ByVal hConnect As Long, ByVal fExpectResponse As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal lpszCommand As String, ByVal dwContext As Long, phFtpCommand As Long) As Long

Private Function test()
    Dim Success As Long
    Dim iRet As Integer
    Dim lngInet As Long
    Dim lngInetConn As Long
    Dim sCommand As String
    Dim test44 As Long
    sCommand = "DIR"
    Dim test5 As Long
    Dim lError As Long
    Dim strBuffer As String
    Dim lBufferSize As Long
    Dim retVal As Long
    lngInet = InternetOpen("MyFTP Control", 1, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0)   'Open connection with fpt
    If lngInet = 0 Then
        iRet = MsgBox("bad")
    Else
        lngInetConn = InternetConnect(lngInet, Server.Value, 0, _
            User.Value, Pass.Value, 1, 0, 0)                                 'Connect to server
        If lngInetConn > 0 Then
            Login = True
            blnRC = FtpCommand(lngInetConn, True, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_ASCII, sCommand, test44, test5)
            retVal = InternetGetLastResponseInfo(lError, strBuffer, lBufferSize)
        Else
            Login = False
            LoginError
        End If
    End If
    InternetCloseHandle (lngInet)   'Close Ftp I thnik is not necessary
    InternetCloseHandle (lngInetConn)   'Close Connection I thnik is not necessary
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There's no `DIR` or `LS` commands in FTP. There's `LIST` command (or `MLSD` or `NLST`).
2. Do not use `FtpCommand` function anyway.

   Use [`FtpFindFirstFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-ftpfindfirstfilew) and [`InternetFindNextFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetfindnextfilew) instead.

Comment: It's any way to send ftp Command directly to ftp not create txt scrip first? I need this because in txt file you can see a password even if i create function which will delete this password is still dangerous when somebody crash the program and the function with deleting password will not run

Comment: I do not get your question. You are not using any script file. You pass the in-memory password to the `InternetConnect`.

Comment: I have another version of this application which was using script to send some file to the server and i was storing there a password but forget about it I send command directly to the cmd and it is working. Thanks for help